# Markup is not getting reflect in update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

In my application I have added web user control inside it I am having some links inside update panel. there are two update panels. If I click on link which is inside first update panel then it will update second update panel. second update panel also contains link buttons if I click on that link button it redirects to same page with query string parameters. so after redirecting to same page my update panels stop working events are getting fire but my markup is not getting change. So If any one having solution for above problem please share.

Comment: Add some code here so it will easy to analyze and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Any sort of Javascript errors showing up in your console?